# Manipulating Excel Table / Pivot via OpenXML

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, openxml, epplus, closedxml

I'm working on an application that will automate the running of Excel reports.

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains a Table and one or more Pivot Tables.  What I need to do is update the contents of the Table via OpenXML and make sure the Pivot Table(s) are set to refresh when the spreadsheet opens.

I have tried using both ClosedXML and EPPlus to modify the Table.  While these libraries have worked when just adjusting the rows of the Table, if columns are either added or removed (which could happen frequently in the reports I'm working with) then the Excel spreadsheet becomes corrupt.  Also, these libraries are hit or miss whether or not they can find the Pivot Table(s) to verify the necessary settings.

I have tried looking into just using the OpenXML SDK but have not been too successful there either.  It seems like such a simple task but it's fighting me like crazy.

I would like to use one of the aforementioned libraries (ClosedXML has been meeting most of my needs and has been my go-to) since they make working with OpenXML so much easier, but if I need to move away from them then so be in.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the pivot table, then modify the source table, then recreate the pivot table?

Comment: I have not. Because every report could have a different pivot table, it would be difficult to recreate it. I have tried deleting the table and just updating the pivot table source but the libraries, while they seem to have the function to delete tables, fail in deleting them. Some minor success I had was deleting the sheet that held the table and adding a whole new sheet. While that worked, when using the libraries to update the pivot source data, the Excel file still became corrupt.

Comment: I can't speak for EPPlus, but in ClosedXML, the pivot tables won't automatically update when you change the columns of the underlying data. There is no live link between pivot tables and the data. I added pivot table support only recently in ClosedXML and it's still very much work in progress. PS: Pivot tables in OpenXML are *not* a simple task. Have a look at the XML that it generates.

Comment: I know that Pivot Table support is still a work in progress for ClosedXML, and the functionality of EPPlus is roughly the same when it comes to Pivots.  I have looked at using straight OpenXML for this but as you said, working with Pivot Tables in OpenXML is not a simple task and it looks very complicated and cumbersome.  However, my main issue comes in with modifying the Excel Table size.  Adding or removing columns is really where I'm hitting the crux of my issues.